# seVoid type cannot be used in onClickListener

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with a method that I want to use in setOnClickListener. I want it to disable the other 2 buttons, which are on top of each other. I have an error:

> 'void' type not allowed here.

Where is the problem?

MainAcitivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RelativeLayout layout;
private Button countof1;
private Button countof10;
private Button countof100;

private int addto=1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    layout = findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    countof1 = findViewById(R.id.countoftoadd1);
    countof10 = findViewById(R.id.countoftoadd10);
    countof100 = findViewById(R.id.countoftoadd100);

    countof1.setOnClickListener(changeAddButton(countof1, countof10, countof100, layout));
    countof10.setOnClickListener(changeAddButton(countof1, countof10, countof100, layout));
    countof100.setOnClickListener(changeAddButton(countof1, countof10, countof100, layout));


}

private void changeAddButton(Button button1, Button button10, Button button100, View view){
    if(addto==1){
        button1.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        this.addto=10;}
    else if(addto==10){
        button1.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        this.addto=100;}
    else{
        button1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        this.addto=1;}
}
```

Comment: Please specify on which line the error is reported.

Answer (score 0):

you should set listener to button:

```
 countof1.setOnClickListener(this);
 countof10.setOnClickListener(this);
 countof100.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and implement `View.OnClickListener` in activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         //...

        countof1.setOnClickListener(this);
        countof10.setOnClickListener(this);
        countof100.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == countof1.getId() || id == countof10.getId() || id == countof100.getId()){
            //call method here
        }
    }
}
```

for this method, you can use `switch` and no need to pass `View` as a parameter

```
private void changeAddButton() {
    switch (addto) {
        case 1:
            button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            addto = 10;
            break;

        case 10:
            button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            addto = 100;
            break;

        default:
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            addto = 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it on my way. Can u take a look about it? It works but i'm not sure that it looks good. Code is in answer

Comment: error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to OnClickListener I tried it but "this" doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @hudyweas make sure you implement `View.OnClickListener` in activity

Comment: Can u tell me why does the onClick look like that? Imo all I need is in the method so this if is not needed

Comment: @hudyweas `View.OnClickListener` is an interface and `onClick(View v)` is a method in that interface. if you set it for each view (like you did in your answer) it will create multiple instances on this interface for each view but you can implement this interface in your activity and override `onClick(View v)` method so when you want to use it, just call `(this)` instead of creating an instance of interface, in this case when you click on a view, `onClick(View v)`  will pass the same view instance so you can check which view clicked by id.

Answer (score 0):

```
countof1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        changeAddButton(countof1,countof10,countof100, layout);
        }
    });

    countof10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeAddButton(countof1,countof10,countof100, layout);
        }
    });

    countof100.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeAddButton(countof1,countof10,countof100, layout);
        }
    });

}

private  void changeAddButton(Button button1, Button button10, Button button100, View view){
    if(addto==1){
        button1.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        button100.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        this.addto=10;}
    else if(addto==10){
        button1.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        button100.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        this.addto=100;}
    else{
        button1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        button100.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        this.addto=1;}
}
```

Comment: it works too, but it's better to add one listener and check it by id

Answer (score 0):

Your current attempt doesn't work because you are calling the method. `changeAddButton` doesn't return anything, so you can't use it as a parameter to `setOnClickListener`, which expects a `View.OnClickListener`.

`changeAddButton` doesn't seem to need the parameters, because you are passing in the same fields every time. So you can rewrite `changeAddButton` to:

```
private void changeAddButton(){
    if(addto==1){
        button1.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        this.addto=10;}
    else if(addto==10){
        button1.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        this.addto=100;}
    else{
        button1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        this.addto=1;}
}
```

And instead of calling it, create a `OnClickListener`:

```
countof1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MainActivity.this.changeAddButton();
    }
});
// do this for the other countofXXXs
```

Or if you [can use Java 8](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support),

```
countof1.setOnClickListener(v -> changeAddButton());
```

EDIT:

Looking at your code more closely, I feel that instead of using three buttons, you should use one button, and change its text from 1, to 10, to 100 using [`setText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)), because that seems like what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I think to make your code working with a few edits you can modify it in this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout layout;
    private Button countof1;
    private Button countof10;
    private Button countof100;

    private int addto=1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout = findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);       //Please consider using standard notation: main_layout
        countof1 = findViewById(R.id.countoftoadd1);   //count_of_to_add_1
        countof10 = findViewById(R.id.countoftoadd10);   //so on
        countof100 = findViewById(R.id.countoftoadd100);

        countof1.setOnClickListener(changeAddButton);
        countof10.setOnClickListener(changeAddButton);
        countof100.setOnClickListener(changeAddButton);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener changeAddButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeAddButtonMethod(countof1, countof10, countof100, layout);
        }
    };

    private void changeAddButtonMethod(Button button1, Button button10, Button button100, View view){
        if(addto==1){
            button1.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            button10.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);     //I think this should be changed to 'button100'
            this.addto=10;}
        else if(addto==10){
            button1.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            button10.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);   //Same as above
            this.addto=100;}
        else{
            button1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            button10.setVisibility(view.GONE);      //Same as above
            this.addto=1;}
    }
}
```

But I think a better way to achieve this is something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout layout;
    private Button countof1;
    private Button countof10;
    private Button countof100;

    private int addto = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout = findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);       //Please consider using standard notation: main_layout
        countof1 = findViewById(R.id.countoftoadd1);   //count_of_to_add_1
        countof10 = findViewById(R.id.countoftoadd10);   //so on
        countof100 = findViewById(R.id.countoftoadd100);

        countof1.setOnClickListener(changeAddButton);
        countof10.setOnClickListener(changeAddButton);
        countof100.setOnClickListener(changeAddButton);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener changeAddButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (addto == 1) {
                countof1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                countof10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                countof100.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                addto = 10;
            } else if (addto == 10) {
                countof1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                countof10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                countof100.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                addto = 100;
            } else {
                countof1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                countof10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                countof100.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                addto = 1;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Or using the answer of Ehsan msz